# How to turn the "this week" button into a dropdown? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using the free admin dashboard template from the bootstrap 4 website, is it possible to turn the "this week" button into a drop down? i have been researching for two days and watching youtube video NO succcess.
Please see code and pics below:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/dashboard/

```js
    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
          </div>

    <!-- BUTTOM I AM TRYING TO CHANGE TO DROP DOWN -->   

          <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
              <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
              This week
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[Pick of screen before code modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrXY8.png)

[Pick after code modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ0T6.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0wt.png)

Comment: i guess you have submitted the different code than which showing Pick after code modification  image for it submit proper corresponding code!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding data-toggle='dropdown' attribute will make dropdown work. check this demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
          </div>

    <!-- BUTTOM I AM TRYING TO CHANGE TO DROP DOWN -->   

          <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
              This week
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks jsduniya it works!! Been trying three days researching how to get it work.. and so simple.. sigh #Codelife

Answer (score 0):

@Samantha In dropdown button you missed to add `data-toggle='dropdown'` attribute.

It should be as below,

```
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
              This week
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're including all the required Javascript files? You didn't show your exact template (just a link to the Bootstrap example) so it's hard to say if you're missing anything. In any case, here's the minimal code for a working demo.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
  This week
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.9.0/feather.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: Hi Kmoser, i think i install all the script, the may not look stocked properly as yours, but they are there..

Comment: @Samantha Did my code work for you? If so, please consider [accepting it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thanks.

Comment: what you said help, but the first response was more to the point. Hence i gave them the tick..

I thought it was the norm to tell everyone thanks that you really appreciate their input. That was very inept of me, I apologise.